# AHK script to login into Windows 7 system

Tags: powershell, windows-7, sendkeys, winlogon

I run a small internet cafe of 15 computers (Windows 7). I have created an admin account and a user account on all of them.

From my own machine at the cash counter, I wish to control login to user accounts on the above machines. (Customer comes, says will sit on system 5, i click a shortcut and system 5 logins with necc. details and customer goes and starts his work). How do I go about doing this?

I have explored Sendkeys, [nirsoft's nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), [powershell calls](http://wasp.codeplex.com/) etc. Nothing seems to work. There are two screens involved. First is the MS logon pictures that need to be clicked, then the password screen followed by 'Enter'.

I am assuming I wish to send something like: AHK_myscript \system1 "user" "password"

Please let me what I need to get past these two screens. (Also have uVNC running, if it helps). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't RDP be a lot easier? mstsc /v:<computername -console  and then just log in and disconnect.

Comment: You would need to find something that runs before the login process. 99.999% of applications don't and can't do this.

Completely a different direction, but something like PGina might end up being "easier" http://pgina.org/

Comment: mjolinor,  RDP, like uVNC, one has to physically login. If only I could hard code username & password to a shortcut... AthomSfere, thanks for suggesting pgina. Will see if that can work. Looks promising. [Time Limit Manager](http://www.fortresgrand.com/products/tlm/tlm.htm) is what I want to achieve on a small/free budget.